# Create an array with evenly-spaced values

Tags: ruby

What is an easy way to generate an array that has values with a fixed distance between them?

For example:

```
1, 4, 7, 10,... etc
```

I need to be able to set start, end, and step distance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try using [`Range.step`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Range.html#M000703):

```
> (1..19).step(3).to_a
=> [1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19]
```

Answer (score 4):

In Ruby 1.9:

```
1.step(12).to_a   #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
1.step(12,3).to_a #=> [1, 4, 7, 10]
```

Or you can *splat* instead of `to_a`:

```
a = *1.step(12,3)  #=> [1, 4, 7, 10]
```